# set different color for specific point on heatmap, using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, heatmap

i print an heatmap of square grid graph based on the value of each node in the graph.
now, i want one node to be color in totally different color from the other, but without destroy the colormap (i don't want just set a very big/small number in this node).
for example, in this heatmap, i want specific node to be color in red:

[image]

any suggestions?
Aviel

Comment: Please post the code that generated this output as a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You could just use a scatter plot for that specific point, e.g. `plt.scatter(xi, yi, color='red', marker='s')`.  Depending on how you want to identify the specific point, you could set its value to `NaN` and use `cmap.set_bad('red')` to differentiate it.